# Why is jupyter resource usage and sys.getsizeof so different?

Tags: memory, jupyter

**In short:** `sys.getsizeof(foo)` returns `~850MB` while jupyter_resource_usage reports `~3.75GB`. Why is it different?

**In long:** I am using python in a jupyter (lab) notebook with the extension jupyter_resource_usage installed.

In a fresh kernel, resource usage status bar reads `Mem: 184.09MB`. I then run

```
import sys
foo = [n for n in range(100_000_000)]
```

Directly afterwards, the status bar reads `Mem: 1.28GB` and after a one-three seconds it updates to `3.96GB`. Meanwhile, `sys.getsizeof(my_var)/1e6` returns `859.72`.
Why the discrepancy?

If I run `del foo` it drops down to `Mem: 187.72MB` again.

Comment: There have been lots of SO about `getsizeof`.  It is nearly useless when applied to a list (measuring only the array of pointers, not the things pointed to.   `getsizeof` is pretty good for numpy arrays, roughly matching the array's own `nbytes`.

Comment: `len(foo)*8` is 800mb, about what I expect for `getsizeof`.  `sys.getsizeof(100_000_000)` is `28`.  So memory use of those numbers is about 28*100_000_000.  For a total of 3.6Gb.  Jupyter is giving a reasonable number.

Comment: Oh! ‍♂️ Obvious when told, but apparently not before... Thank you!