# Memory Usage Overhead for Numpy NDarray vs Tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, numpy-ndarray

I've been searching around but couldn't find anything useful and the medium article I found was very much not as informative as I thought. I would like to know the memory overhead usage for tensor vs numpy since I need to store a very large array to process it later.

I tried using getsizeof but I found some interesting results.
Here's my result:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]], dtype=int32)>

In [66]: sys.getsizeof(ts1)
Out[66]: 168

In [67]: ts
Out[67]:
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])>

In [68]: sys.getsizeof(ts)
Out[68]: 168
```

For tensor, it seems like the number of bytes being used is the same regardless of the type and I am not sure why.

```
In [52]: nmpy = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], dtype = "int32")

In [53]: sys.getsizeof(nmpy)
Out[53]: 156

In [54]: nmpy1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], dtype = "int64")
In [55]: sys.getsizeof(nmpy1)
Out[55]: 192
```

As for numpy, it makes a bit more sense since I was able to calculate the overhead size for this particular array.

3 x 3 x int32 = 36 bytes
3 x 3 x int64 = 72 bytes

156 - 36 = 120 bytes
192 - 72 = 120 bytes

Although I can't figure out what the extra 120 bytes is storing. Reading older post, I'm assume it is just storing pointers to numpy's attribute such as their interal length and such.

If anyone can provide me with a good resource on how to measure the overhead for these two, I would highly appreciate it. Thank you for reading my post.

Comment: There have been a lot of SO about `getsizeof`.  Yes, you do have to understand what it is measuring.  For `numpy` arrays it does include the data-buffer, so it is close to the `nbytes` (provided it isn't a `view`).  I just demonstrated in another current SO how to estimate the usage of a list.  I don't know how a tensor stores its data, but your numbers suggest that it only gets the "core" object size, not any of the data.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75962389/why-is-jupyter-resource-usage-and-sys-getsizeof-so-different

Comment: A numpy array has to store attributes like `shape`, `strides` and `dtype`.  Look at the `getsizeof` of a int; I get `28`, not `8` (the data bytes of a int or float).

Comment: @hpaulj to be pedantic, `int` objects are arbitrarily sized (as long as you have enough address space)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, and further pedantry, small ints are unique and preallocated.  I quioted 28 from my previous answer with values up to 100_000_000.

Comment: The display of your tensor tells me that it contains an array as an attribute. I don't know if that's always the case, but here, the tensor just adds a lay of overhead.  It may add some useful functionality (methods), but if your focus is memory use, it doesn't do anything for you.  Of course for "normal" large arrays, the 'overhead', whether array or tensor is minor, measured in hundreds of bytes, where as the data could well be Mb or Gb.